# Docker ignores step for same image name

Tags: docker

I am new to docker, to understand i am trying to build a simple image, but in my case some of the steps in build is ignored if I use the same image name again.

I am sure i am doing it wrong, but just don't understand why this is happening.

below is the dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu AS base
COPY ./runner1/data /app

FROM base
COPY ./runner1/dep /app

FROM base AS final
COPY ./runner1/sample.sh /app/sample.sh
RUN chmod u+x /app/sample.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/app/sample.sh" ]
```

```
Building runner1
Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu AS base
 ---> 94e814e2efa8
Step 2/8 : COPY ./runner1/data /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 675aabaf1cc0

Step 3/8 : FROM base
 ---> 675aabaf1cc0
Step 4/8 : COPY ./runner1/dep /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dcd1a390efd3

Step 5/8 : FROM base AS final
 ---> 675aabaf1cc0
Step 6/8 : COPY ./runner1/sample.sh /app/sample.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 99b286322a7c
Step 7/8 : RUN chmod u+x /app/sample.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3599903cb1b8
Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/app/sample.sh" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 977e3379ab8c

Successfully built 977e3379ab8c
Successfully tagged sampleimage_runner1:latest
```

When this is run, I see only /app/data folder copied from image '675aabaf1cc0', image 'dcd1a390efd3' from step 3,4 appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You set base as the parent image to your second stage, but you never used your second stage anywhere else. I believe you can explicitly build with target set to 2 to see the image that results from this.

If you intended to use the output from stage 2 as your parent image of stage 3, then you need to name your second stage, and use the name of that second stage as your parent for stage 3. E.g.

```
FROM ubuntu AS base
COPY ./runner1/data /app

FROM base as middle
COPY ./runner1/dep /app

FROM middle AS final
COPY ./runner1/sample.sh /app/sample.sh
RUN chmod u+x /app/sample.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/app/sample.sh" ]
```

Comment: Can please explain why do I need an intermediate image. Shouldn't step 5 use the same base image as whatever got updated till step 4 ?

Comment: No, because stage 2 created a new unnamed image. Stage 3 pulled the image you named in stage 1. You don't change a previous stage when you use it, you only extend it with new layers. If you want to use that new extended image, you need to specify to use that specific image.